# Tier pricing rounding - to show float number for SAVE 3.55%

Tags: magento-1.9, price, overrides, tierprice, rounding

There is problem with "You save %" on tier prices. It shows only integer and I many cases this looks strange like, without desired precision.

- Buy 4 for 29.69 each and save extra 2%
- Buy 6 for 29.39 each and save **extra 3%**
- Buy 12 for 29.10 each and save **extra 3%**

Users are confused with 2 tiers - which shows they save the same percent amount.

How to overcome this and show exact % save with 2 digits float.

Comment: please post what code you are using to show tier prices.

Comment: This is pure Magento code. I just like to show 3.35% instead of rounded 3%